# How can I store this in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I must write a dictionary. This is my first time doing it and I can't wrap my head around it. The first 5 element should be the key to it and the rest the value.

```py
for i in verseny:
    if i not in eredmeny:
        eredmeny[i] = 1

    else:
        eredmeny[i] += 1
```

`YS869 CCCADCADBCBCCB` this is a line from the hw. This `YS869` should be the key and this `CCCADCADBCBCCB` should be the value.

The problem is that I can't store them in a dictionary. I'm grinding gears here but getting nowhere.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I can't store them in a dictionary. I dont' know how :/

Comment: Can you share your full code? I have no idea what's going on in the snippet.

Comment: It's a bunched with other tasks but I can.

Comment: ```
beolv = open("C:\\Users\\karol\\Documents\infoshit\\e_inffor_17maj\\Forrasok\\4_Tesztverseny\\valaszok.txt","r")
verseny = beolv.readlines()
print("A fájl sikeresen be lett olvasva és tárolva")

seged1 = 0

for i in range(len(verseny)-1):
    seged1 += 1

print("A vetélkedőn" + " " + str(seged1)+ " " + "vett részt")


eredmeny = {}

azonkeres = input("Kérem adja meg a keresett azonosítót:")

for i in verseny:
    if i not in eredmeny:
        eredmeny[i] = 1

    else:
        eredmeny[i] += 1

for j,k in eredmeny.items():
    print(str(k))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `erdemeny` is your dictionary name and that `verseny` is the list that includes your values and keys strings. This should do it:

```
verseny = ['YS869 CCCADCADBCBCCB', 'CS769 CCCADCADBCBCCB', 'BS869 CCCADCADBCBCCB']
eredmeny = {}

for i in verseny:
    key, value = i.split(' ')[0], i.split(' ')[1]
    if key not in eredmeny.keys():
        eredmeny[key] = value
    else:
        eredmeny[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Seriously! Much love and appreciations to you and @alec_a for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding the question well, but an easy way to do the task at hand would be converting the list into a string and then using `split()`:

```
line = 'YS869 CCCADCADBCBCCB'
words = l.split()
d = {ls[0]: ls[1]}

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the basic skill in python. I hope you can refer to the existing materials. As your example, the following demonstrations are given:

```py
line = 'YS869 CCCADCADBCBCCB'
dictionary = {}
dictionary[line[:4]] = line[5:]

print(dictionary)  # {'YS86': ' CCCADCADBCBCCB'}
```